# Workaround for a circular reference in excel

Tags: excel-formula, circular-reference

I have a cash flow model forecast that I would like to reduce the ending balance by whatever the difference over $2,000 is by using financing activities but this causes an intended circular reference.

[image]

The image above is purely an example and we will assume that June on-wards is our forecast numbers and January to May is actual numbers.

To give context:

`C11 = SUM(C7:C10)`,

`C13 = SUM(C11,C4,C2)`,

`C14 = B15` (its the ending balance from the prior month),

`C15 = SUM(C13:C14)`,

`C17 = IF(C15>=2000,C15-2000,0)`.

So from June G15 on-wards I'm forecasting we will always have more than $2,000 and I want to reduce $2,341 to $2,000 by adding it to G7 as a negative number. The formula in G7 will be:

`-IF(G17>0,G17,0)`

Which makes G11 $(341), G13 becomes $878, and  G15 becomes $2,000 Yay!... but here alas is my circular reference because when you press F9 G17 becomes 0 and it all reverts back to what it was before.

Ultimately I'm trying to change row 15 in the forecast period by using row 15 in the first pass.

I should mention that I have iterative calculation turned on to allow the calculation to run.

Every month where I forecast over $2,000 I want to pay of some debt in Row 7 by whatever amount is over $2,000 but in the same month, then carryover the $2,000 or whatever is the balance to the next month and repeat the process.

So initially by June ending I forecast $2,341, then I decide the $341 goes to pay some debt in the same June leaving me with only $2,000 by end of June.

I carryover the 2,000 to July and add it to H14 and if I am below $2,000 no debt pay down just carryover to the next month until I am above $2,00 again and then pay down debt

I would appreciate suggestions on how to do that. Let me know if more clarification is needed.

Maybe some VBA?

Thanks

Comment: Just a curiosity, would you not pay the long term debt from the excess of the previous month after the money is realized not based on an assumption?

Comment: @Scott Craner Great question! There are some debt ratios we need to adhere to, a very important one is a debt covenant ratio and we have found paying down debt within the month we reach (in this scenario) $2,000 we maintain that ratio.

Comment: Have you considered using the Solver?